# Resizing rotated image in chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, rotation

I am using jquery ui resizable.

When I rotate the element in chrome, the controls get rotated too but when I resize the div with handles, they are inverted.

Normal scenario should be; if I resize the image inwards, it should reduce and if I resize it outwards, it should increase its size.

This is fine for non-rotated images but it is not the case for rotated images.

Here is the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fahadnabbasi/2FLuf/11/

Comment: I have the same problem, also in Firefox and safari